# Visual Studio: Automatic COM registration with dependant DLLs outside Debug/Release dirs

Tags: visual-c++, com, dependencies, registration

I've written some unmanaged C++ COM DLLs that rely on native C++ DLLs not in the system path.  When I build the associated projects without copying the DLLs into the Debug/Release directories I get the infamous PRJ0050 compiler error.

Clearly I could copy required DLLs all around the solution, but I'd like to avoid this.  I know I could set project properties Linker->"Register Output" to No and then run regsvr32 directly during a post build step.

My question is if there's a better way to do this.  Is there a way to use the automatic "Register Output" option with a custom path controlled at the project level?  What am I missing here?

**Edit:** Originally I'd been thinking "Register Output" did some magic like un-registering on a clean, but that isn't the case.  The only thing special it seems to do is pick out the proper way to register different types of projects.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking - but there are post build steps you can do.  For example - if these are 3rd party libraries/DLLs you can have them located in a known relative path or in a directory named by an environment variable.

This is not an unusual scenario from what I can tell of your situation.

Can you add a DLL as part of the project (wherever it is located) and as the build step for that do the registration.  Or you can make the build step for that a file copy and registration

Again - I am not exactly sure what you are asking and why your 2nd paragraph is not acceptable to you if it works

Comment: Adding a DLL to the project doesn't seem to help the register step pick it up.  (File copy does)  I'd been thinking that "Register Output" did some extra steps like unregistering the DLL on a clean, but apparently it doesn't do that, so for now I've been using a custom registration build step.